# Why am I not seeing output in the terminal after executing python script?

Tags: python, scrapy

Im following a tutorial @: https://blog.scrapinghub.com/category/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros/ ~ The code seems to execute fine, but Im not seeing any output to the terminal.. Im still trying to figure out how to use a "stack trace with python..., to see if there is a issue on the back-end", Problem is that I am not seeing any output in the terminal after executing the script.. Any help would be great..

```
import scrapy

class SpidyQuotesViewStateSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spidyquotes-viewstate'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/search.aspx']
    download_delay = 1.5

    def parse(self, response):
      for author in response.css('select#author > option ::attr(value)').extract():
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/filter.aspx',
            formdata={
                'author': author,
                '__VIEWSTATE': response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first()
            },
            callback=self.parse_tags
        )




     def parse_tags(self, response):
        for tag in response.css('select#tag > option ::attr(value)').extract():
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                'http://quotes.toscrape.com/filter.aspx',
                formdata={
                    'author': response.css(
                        'select#author > option[selected] ::attr(value)'
                    ).extract_first(),
                    'tag': tag,
                    '__VIEWSTATE': response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first()
                },
                callback=self.parse_results,
            )

     def parse_results(self, response):
       for quote in response.css("div.quote"):
            yield {
                'quote': quote.css('span.content ::text').extract_first(),
                'author': quote.css('span.author ::text').extract_first(),
                'tag': quote.css('span.tag ::text').extract_first(),
            }
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given code has no active execution.  This is nothing more than a class definition.  To get output, you need to continue in the tutorial to write a driver (main) program that will instantiate an object of the class and make a call or two to actually scrape the given web sites.

You don't get a "stack trace" unless your program crashes (elicits an fatal exception).  It's not something you implement and "use".

Answer (score 0):

Save the file in the spider directory of your project and then do 
`scray crawl spidyquotes-viewstate -o viewstate.json` and the results will be in `viewstate.json` in your current directory.